# Why is Spring Boot not recognizing @Bean inside subpackage @Configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I am setting up a project in Kotlin with Spring Security for login support. I am new to Spring Boot, so comments could be helpful. I have problem with Spring Boot not scanning my `@Configuration` class and inject the `@Bean` defined inside it. However, it recognized the same `@Bean` inside the `@SpringBootApplication` class.

I am not using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` because it is now deprecated.

Using `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`, I was able to confirm that spring boot recognized beans only when using `@SpringBootApplication`. While using `@Configuration`, it did NOT find it.

I don't want the bean to be there. I want to separate the bean into its own configuration file, in a subpackage, using the `@Configuration`. How do I do that?

---

Here is a screenshot of the found bean when debugging, and the bean was defined in `@SpringBootApplication`.
[image: LogWithPilterChain]

---

#### Here I have the different relevant class defintions:

##### Main class

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {
    // @Bean  // <--- this bean is recognized
    // fun pilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    //  http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic()
    //  return http.build()
    // }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args) 
}
```

##### Controller class

```kotlin
@RestController
class MessageResource {
    @GetMapping
    fun index(): String = "Hello World"
}
```

##### SecurityConfig.kt in subpackage

```kotlin
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean // <--- this bean is not recognized
    fun pilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic()
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit 1: Add project structure

[image]

Comment: You hide some details & tldr, but sounds like [just structuring your code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) could help!?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Wow, I really forgot to add the package declaration. Thank you and xerx593. This works now. This is such a noob mistake I did here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `SecurityConfig` is in a package that is not the same package of your `DemoApplication` or a child package of the package of `DemoApplication`.

To solve it move the package of `SecurityConfig` to the package of `DemoApplication`. It will then become a child package and should work.